# How to get image.url from ElasticSearch model indexed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, elasticsearch

Does anybody know how can i get a image.url from a image indexed in elasticsearcg (using tire) ?

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Tire::Model::Search
   include Tire::Model::Callbacks
   attr_accessible :caption, :user_id, :image, :venue_id
   attr_accessible :id, :image_file_name, :created_at, :updated_at, :city, :state, :country, :image_url
   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "9999x9999", :medium => "300x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end

class SearchController < ApplicationController
   def index
   city_name = params[:city]
   @photos = Photo.search city_name
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
   end
end
```

end

In my index.html.erb when i do:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= image_tag photo.image.url(:medium) %>
```

i receive a undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Can anybody help me ?

Thank y very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add to your Photo model:

```
mapping do
  indexes :image
end

def image
  picture.url(:medium)
end
```

After in your view

```
<%= image_tag photo.image %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is contained in the SQL database your model is stored in, so you need your search function to query ElasticSearch, then look up the corresponding entries in that database. This is accomplished by passing `load: true` to `Photo.search`.

`@photos = Photo.search city_name, load: true`